# How to remove particular row in my table using with Angular.js?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am checking two check boxes in first table those records are adding in second table this is fine. But if unchecked record removing as improper way, how can I remove exact row I unchecked.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        itemID: 'BR063',
        itemValue: 'sagsfgjkfdsffsdfsd'
    }, {
        itemID: 'BR06417',
        itemValue: '1231231231123'
    }];
 $scope.selectedItems = [];
  
 $scope.addRec = function(result, i){
    if(result == true){
     
     $scope.selectedItems.push($scope.items[i-1]);
    }
    else{ 
      $scope.selectedItems.splice($scope.items[i],1);
    }
 }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<div ng-app = 'myApp' ng-controller="homeCtrl">
<h1>Select Rows</h1>
<table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
<tr>
<th class="text-center">Index</th>
<th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
<th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
<th class="text-center">Select</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in items">
<td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="itsVal" ng-change = "addRec(itsVal, $index+1)";/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<h1>Selected Rows</h1>
<table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
<tr>
<th class="text-center">Index</th>
<th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
<th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
<th class="text-center">Select</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in selectedItems">
<td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"  /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>
```

Comment: Hi Samudrala - how did you get on with the answers below? There is much help below, which has not elicited much in the way of responses from you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do `$scope.selectedItems.splice(i-1, 1);` in the `else` block. Also since `result` is a boolean value you can simply use `if (result)` in the condition:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    itemID: 'BR063',
    itemValue: 'sagsfgjkfdsffsdfsd'
  }, {
    itemID: 'BR06417',
    itemValue: '1231231231123'
  }];
  $scope.selectedItems = [];

  $scope.addRec = function(result, i) {
    if (result) {
      $scope.selectedItems.push($scope.items[i - 1]);
    } else {
      $scope.selectedItems.splice(i-1, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <h1>Select Rows</h1>
  <table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Index</th>
      <th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
      <th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
      <th class="text-center">Select</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in items">
      <td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="itsVal" ng-change="addRec(itsVal, $index+1)" ;/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h1>Selected Rows</h1>
  <table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Index</th>
      <th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
      <th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
      <th class="text-center">Select</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in selectedItems">
      <td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to remove via index rather than using the id. Have made some changes in the **addRec** function and the line in html invoking it. Please go through them once:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        itemID: 'BR063',
        itemValue: 'sagsfgjkfdsffsdfsd'
    }, {
        itemID: 'BR06417',
        itemValue: '1231231231123'
    }];
 $scope.selectedItems = [];
  
 $scope.addRec = function(result, i,itemId){
    if(result == true){
     
     $scope.selectedItems.push($scope.items[i-1]);
    }
    else{ 
              var index=0;
              var isMatched = false;
              angular.forEach($scope.selectedItems,function(item)    {
                   if(isMatched === false)    {
                          if(item.itemID === itemId)    {
                           isMatched = true;
                          }
                          else    {
                            index++;
                          }
                   }
                   
              });
      $scope.selectedItems.splice(index,1);
    }
 }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<div ng-app = 'myApp' ng-controller="homeCtrl">
<h1>Select Rows</h1>
<table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
<tr>
<th class="text-center">Index</th>
<th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
<th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
<th class="text-center">Select</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in items track by x.itemID">
<td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="itsVal" ng-change = "addRec(itsVal, $index+1,x.itemID)";/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<h1>Selected Rows</h1>
<table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
<tr>
<th class="text-center">Index</th>
<th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
<th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
<th class="text-center">Select</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in selectedItems track by x.itemID">
<td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"  /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>
```

Comment: if checked and unchecked that checkbox its showing below error  {
  "message": "[ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=x%20in%20selectedItems&p1=object%3A4&p2=%7B%22itemID%22%3A%22BR06417%22%2C%22itemValue%22%3A%221231231231123%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A4%22%7D",
  "filename": undefined,
  "lineno": undefined,
  "colno": undefined
}

Comment: Corrected by adding track by...try now

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `directive` as you **don't need to repeat the code for table rendering**, and use a filter to sort out the selected rows!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("tableRenderer", function(){
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
    template: `
     <table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Index</th>
      <th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
      <th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
      <th class="text-center">Select</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in list | filter:filter">
      <td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.selected" ;/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    `,
    scope: {
     list: '=',
        filter: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
     
    }
  }
})
app.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    itemID: 'BR063',
    itemValue: 'sagsfgjkfdsffsdfsd',
    selected: false
  }, {
    itemID: 'BR06417',
    itemValue: '1231231231123',
    selected: false
  }];
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <h1>Select Rows</h1>
  <table-renderer list="items"></table-renderer>

  <h1>Selected Rows</h1>
  <table-renderer list="items" filter="{selected: true}"></table-renderer>
  <div>
```